# Filtering within an annotate() query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am making a django app with comments and voting on those comments, in the stackoverflow or reddit style. When selecting the comments, I would like to know both the aggregate vote count, and whether the user has voted on this particular comment. I can use annotate for the aggregate count like so:

```
video_comments = Comment.objects.filter(video_id=video_id).annotate(vote_sum=Sum('commentvote__value'))
```

Can I also annotate a subset of the commentvotes? Something like:

```
.annotate(user_vote=Sum('commentvote__value').filter(commentvote__user == user))
```

For reference, this is my model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    video_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, db_index=True)
    video_time = models.FloatField()

    comment = models.TextField(max_length=MAX_COMMENT_LENGTH)

    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class CommentVote(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, db_index=True)
    value = models.IntegerField() # Should be 1 or -1

    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True)
```

Comment: You might want to add `unique_together = ('comment', 'user')` to `CommentVote`. Also, `db_index` on `ForeignKeys` is not necessary in MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz! I missed that unique_together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses), you can filter on a given field before annotating:

```
Comment.objects.filter(video_id=video_id).filter(commentvote__user=user))\
               .annotate(user_vote=Sum('commentvote__value'))
```

Unfortunately this narrows the comment set to just those comments which have vote(s) cast by given user. But you can also get the remaining comments:

```
Comment.objects.filter(video_id=video_id).exclude(commentvote__user=user))
```

and combine both lists manually.

Comment: Btw this is also now exactly what the OP needs, but I cannot make two annotations on the same related model work simulatnously, if one is "global" and the second one filtered..

Comment: Argh, "now" should be "not" in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give you what you require:

```
CommentVote.objects.values('comment').filter(comment__video_id=video_id,user=user).annotate(vote_sum=Sum('value')).values_list('comment','vote_sum',)
```

Comment: Could I please know the mistake that I have committed in this answer?

Comment: According to me it just doesn't do what you advertise it should do. But if you prove that it works then I'll happily reverse the vote.

Comment: Hey Tomasz, I have found a possible mistake. The filter should be placed before the annotate. Is there anymore mistakes?

Comment: Your query is now equivalent to: CommentVote.objects.filter(user=user, comment__video_id=video_id).values_list('comment', 'value'), i.e. it filters votes by given user for given video and returns `comment_id` and `value` (disguised as vote_sum) for them.

Comment: I think (and it works as well) that the `annotate` would work based on `values('comment')` for the `particular video_id and user`. `values_list` is next in the process. Please correct me, if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Check the resulting SQL for the query, it shows everything. Basically the annotation doesn't sum anything.

Comment: After generating the query, I got `SELECT "commentvote"."comment_id", SUM("commentvote"."value") AS "vote_sum" FROM "commentvote" INNER JOIN "comment" ON("commentvote"."comment_id" = "comment"."id") WHERE ("comment"."video_id" = 1  AND "commentvote"."user_id" = 2 ) GROUP BY "commentvote"."comment_id"`. Here I have taken video_id=1 and user_id=2

Comment: You SELECT CommentVote.id and also GROUP BY CommentVote.id. And because for each CommentVote.id there is exactly one Comment, this aggregation does nothing useful and what you end up with is: `CommentVote.objects.filter(user=user, comment__video_id=video_id).values_list('comment', 'value')`.

Comment: Hey Tomasz, there is confusion in what you see. `comment_id` and `comment.id` are two different fields in the model and can be seen from the model in the question as well. `comment_id` is the `comment field` of the model which is a `ForeignKey` and `comment.id` is the field which is **auto-created** by `django` and which is the `Primary Key` and I have not used it anywhere as can be seen. Please have a second look at the `Select` that has been generated. Moreover, I have also tested by **actually creating the above models** with `test data` and `designing test-cases` as well.

Comment: No, there is no confusion, I just looked at the wrong query in my shell :) So, your current query is equivalent to: `Comment.objects.filter(commentvote__user=2, video_id=1).annotate(vote_sum=models.Sum('commentvote__value')).values_list('id', 'vote_sum')` which is still not what OP wants, but at least returns proper data so I'm removing the downvote. To be honest I'm not convinced that one can do that magic in one query without resorting to `.extra()` or `.raw()`